# What is the probability that a nonce is a solution for the block

Tags: mining-technical-details, technical-details

What is the probability that a nonce is a solution for the block . In the sense how many times we have to change nonce to solve the block

Answer (score 1):

Every hash means one guess. Currently Monero network has ~2.3 GHash/s hashrate and blocks get find every ~120 second.

~2.3 * ~120 = ~282 Ghash required to find a block.
282 Ghash means 282,000,000,000 Hash